# To what extent is immature eggs in insects (beetles) a good approximation for maximum fecundity?

Tags: ecology, entomology, population-biology

To what extent is the number of immature eggs from dissected, newly emerged individuals a reasonable approximation for maximum/potential fecundity in insects (more specifically beetles)? I know that many species must feed for the eggs to become mature and viable. However, can a comparison between species on immature eggs still be used to capture the range of maximum fecundity between species or to accurately rank species from low---high fecundity?

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of things to clarify here; **Fecundity** is the number of offspring that is produced by an individual, and this can be separated into **potential fecundity** (maximum reproductive capacity) and **realized fecundity** (number of offspring actually produced). **Realized fecundity** is very similar to **fertility**, which is defined as the number of viable offspring that are produced.

**Potential fecundity** can sometimes be a good proxy for future fertility, and this is especially true for species where all eggs are present after metamorphosis of the adult insect ([Awmack & Leather, 2002](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.ento.47.091201.145300)). However, in some species the formation of eggs is a continuous process in adult individuals, and this is relatively common in beetles. Therefore, the number of immature eggs might be a poor proxy of both potential and realized fecundity in these species ([Awmack & Leather, 2002](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.ento.47.091201.145300)), and this is more likely in relatively long-lived species that feed extensively as adults. In beetle species that do not feed as adults (often lacking functional mouthparts), immature eggs is probably a better approximation of potential fecundity.

It should also be mentioned that the quality of host plants will often affect the maturation of eggs ([Sterns & Smith, 1960](http://hilgardia.ucanr.edu/Abstract/?a=hilg.v29n10p411); [Hopkins & Ekbom, 1999](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00008823)), and will therefore also determine to what extent the number of immature eggs is a good indication of potential fecundity. When feeding on poor quality hosts eggs may e.g. be reabsorbed by females to use for other purposes (see references in [Awmack & Leather, 2002](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.ento.47.091201.145300) & [Hopkins & Ekbom, 1999](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00008823) for further information).

The review paper by [Awmack & Leather, 2002](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.ento.47.091201.145300) is very comprehensive, and contains a wealth of useful references on this topic.